# Regarding Placing Footer Under the Pages Content with the contents border bottom visible

Tags: html, css

I want my footer to appear directly under the content which is containing the dropbox shawdow , the bottom border of the content has to be shown but the footer should appear below or in other words underneath the content , I can have a footer placed in my page but have no idea how to push the footer under the content with contents border visible

Any help regarding this will be useful to me

I need it to be done in html4 not in html 5

I have done the following  for the footer in the style sheet as follows , now am able to push the footer underneath the content  but i dont want the width of the footer to resize on window resize , the footer width has to be 100% no matter what , and in Internet Explorer am unable to use position :absolute , any help will be greatly appreciated

```
#footer
{ 
position:absolute;
top:718px;
z-index:-1;
width:100%;
left:0; 
height:100px;
background: #EDEDED ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS's z-index:

```
#content {z-index: 10;}
footer {z-index: 1;}
```

(Note the HTML5 element 'footer')